# Who said, "Heresies Survive by the Truths They Retain"?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, heresy

On pg. 7 of the 1938 edition of *The Great Heresies* by Hilaire Belloc, he writes:

> Wherefore it is said of heresies that ``they survive by the truths they retain.''

He does not seem to specify who said this originally.

Does anyone know who first said, "Heresies survive by the truths they retain."?